# below ajax call fails to call ajax_news.php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function track_Function(menuid)
{    
 alert(menuid);      
           var url = "ajax_news.php"

           jQuery.ajax({
                url:"ajax_news.php",
                data:"name=name",
                cache : false,
                dataType : "html",


                success: function(data){
                alert("data saved"+data);           
                }
            });           

}

</script>

<h3><a href="news.php" onclick="track_Function(<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>);"> <?php echo $row['title'];?></a>
```

this ajax call fails to  call file ajax_news.php

Comment: have you included the google ajax library before calling ajax?

Comment: You need to do 2 things: Check if you have included `jQuery`, and post the error that you get in the browser console.

Comment: You need check HTTP Status code as well. It may give incorrect PHP file path like that also check with console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>

    function track_Function(menuid)
    {
       alert(menuid);  

       var url = "ajax_news.php"

       $.ajax({
            url:"ajax_news.php",
            data:"name=name",
            cache : false,
            dataType : "html",
            success: function(data){
                alert("data saved"+data);
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

use

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
```

to be able to use jQuery.

the other thing

```
jQuery.ajax
```

should be

```
$.ajax
```

Comment: Using a `$` sign works fine.

Comment: hey i have use this code now its works in IE ,crome but fails to work with mozilla

Comment: @user3172359 , if my answer was correct please use the icon to show it.

Comment: if i use your code for onclick event of button it works proper but it fails when use with onclick event of hyperlink why so

Comment: @user3172359 , I dont know. I think you can't handle onclick on hyperlinks becuase they have there own event. If my code worked please use the answer icon by clicking on it.

Comment: how to handle hyperlink event ... can you help me

Answer (score 1):

first try to change this:

```
data:"name=name",
```

to this:

```
data:{name: name},
```

Comment: still it giving problem

Comment: which error return into your console?@user3172359

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$.ajax({ url: '/my/site',
         data: {action: 'test'},
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output) {
                      alert(output);
                  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check HTTP Status code in browser console this will so much information. 
Make sure your relative path is correct.
Also `setup error handler` for your AJAX service so that you find root cause.

```
var inputData = { name: 'MyName' };      

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",//GET    
    url: "ajax_news.php",
    cache : false,
    dataType : "html",
    data: inputData,
    success: function (data) {
        var response = data;//output as html    
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
       alert("Error occurred...!" + status);
    }   
});
```

Comment: hey thanx now it s working

Answer (score 0):

first include jquery.min.js file. then

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function track_Function(menuid) 
{
   var url = "ajax_news.php";
   jQuery.post(url,{
     name1 : data1,
     name2 : data2
   },
 function(response)
 {
  //print this response on special div or other functions .....
 }
);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i think your problem is the fact that you are calling the ajax function onclick of a anchor tag.

This in general refreshes the page before it does the ajax call.

So think to call your ajax function onclick of some other tag.

Comment: its work in IE ,opera , crome but fails to work with mozilla 26.0 ajax_news.php ran Db is also reflecting  changes but it gives status text=error ready state=0 responsetext=empty